# parse csv row by row in R

Tags: r, csv

I want to iterate over a csv row by row.
Normally I would use read.csv, the problem is, I have no typical header, the names are not in the first row but in the first column.

For instance:

```
name1 1 2 3
name2 6 9 0
name3 8 7 0
```

...

Is there a way for this?

Comment: Are the data types the same in each column? If so you can use `read.csv(..., header=FALSE)` and won't have to read row by row.

Comment: No, they are not: There are Numbers everywhere, only the first column consists of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read it in with `read.csv()` and then transpose it:

```
df = read.csv('row_csv.csv', sep=' ', header=FALSE, row.names=1)
df_fixed = data.frame(t(df))
```

Once that's done, you can delete the rownames to get them back to normal:

```
rownames(df_fixed) = NULL
df_fixed
```

Result:

```
  name1 name2 name3
1     1     6     8
2     2     9     7
3     3     0     0
```

Comment: I guess that does the trick, only have to find out how to print the things from Java. If that works I will vote, of course.

Comment: did not work for me however. I get: X1 X0 X2 X1.3
1  0  1  0    0
2  1  0  0    1
3  0  0  1    0
4  0  0  0    1
5 NA NA NA   NA

Comment: admited I uses other data (my vectors consisting only of 0 and 1 and of yourse the names) but still this should not have happend

Comment: @newnewbie: My answer worked with the example data you originally had. Maybe edit a small sample of your actual data into your question?

Comment: Sorry, spent part of yesterday on a train, so a rather late answer. Well, it DOES work, but I get a fourth row of NA. else I get the same as you.

Comment: If I do that with any other data then yours row.names = 1 will not be accepted because of a mistake roughly translated as "double row.names not allowed". Why might that be?